# Java 8 appears to be installed but in fact is not (macOS)

Tags: mac, java

I downloaded  Java 8 from oracle.com, and  I installed it.
Nothing unusual.
But when I type java I get: No Java runtime present, requesting install.
And if I go to settings the java icon is there!

Comment: your installation directory should be in PATH. what is the output of `echo $PATH`

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Apple/bin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands

Comment: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java

Comment: the path to the java

Comment: @MANGUSTANobody try adding `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin` instead of `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java` to your path

Comment: nope,not working

Comment: Or create an alias from the java binary to /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `jenv` and Homebrew together to manage Java installations and environments, especially as you're working from the command line.

Install `jenv`

```
brew install jenv
```

Then install the java version you want, Java 8 is annoying bc it's not in Homebrew itself anymore, but this works

```
brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
```

Then add it to `jenv`

```
jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Then set it as the global `java`

```
jenv global 1.8
```

Now `java -version` is

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

---

`jenv` has been very useful to me as a Java developer for managing and switching between all my different Java versions. It also conveniently lets you set versions specific to projects/directories with `jenv local`

Comment: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home is not a valid path to java installation

Comment: at the second step : Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/adoptopenjdk/homebrew-openjdk /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/adoptopenjdk/homebrew-openjdk --depth=1` exited with 128.